# How do I print a functions format on racket?

Tags: racket

this is my code

```
#lang racket
(define (myPolynomial x)
  (- (- (* 9 (* x x)) (* 3 x)) 25))

(define (myOtherPolynomial x)
  (- (- (* 11 (* x x)) (* 2 x)) 50))
```

How can I print the format of this function without having to do something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define (myPolynomial x)
  (- (- (* 9 (* x x)) (* 3 x)) 25))

(define (printPolynomial)
  (display (format "y = 9x^2 - 3x - 25")))

; Example usage
(printPolynomial)
```

I've tried

```
(display myPolynomial
```

but I just get:#procedure:myPolynomial

I was expecting it to print: y = 9x^2.....

Comment: @Shawn I don't think so.. I'm not trying to get my functions to calculate anything. (well that's not the purpose of my post I have already worked through that) I have my functions written out I just want it to print them without having to manually turn it into a string.

Comment: Like the dupe says, Racket doesn't keep the source of functions anywhere, just the compiled machine code. So you have to preserve it yourself; the answer gives an implementation that does that.

Comment: If you're not trying to calculate anything, do you really want to be defining functions?

Comment: @Shawn got it. I was just trying to make the output more legible. Im new to racket but that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: It all comes down to data representation. Eg. if I denote polymomials by n1*x^n starting at zero such as your two polinomials can be represented as `'(-25 -3 9)` and `'(-50 -2 11)` you can easily write a procedure to print it as well as a procedure that takes this input and generates the procedure that takes `x` and returns `f(x)`